# How to have a single query string per SignalR hub?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr-hub

I have two hubs on one page and they both do different things. You can see in the snap shot below that the error is showing two hubs, it's also shows two hubs on the client.

Is there a way for each Hub to have it's own query string? because right now both hubs receive the same query string parameter.

I need for each hub to have it's own query string or something similar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[You just can't do that](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiplehubs)

> All Hubs get the same HTTP request  information.
>
> Since all Hubs share the same connection, the only HTTP request
>   information that the server gets is what comes in the original HTTP
>   request that establishes the SignalR connection. If you use the
>   connection request to pass information from the client to the server
>   by specifying a query string, you can't provide different query
>   strings to different Hubs. All Hubs will receive the same information.

Unless, maybe, you specify another connection for the other hub.